# VSCode debug Expo project: "Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, expo

I try to use vscode to debug Expo project. 
The expo works fine, setting are as bellow:

```
Expo XDE: Host: Tunnel
          Development Mode
iOS Simulator: Enable Remote Debugging
```

But when I add `Debug in Exponent` in VSCode, and click debug,
it will pop up `Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly` without showing any further information.
`DEBUG CONSOLE` show nothing.

What should I do to finding out what's going on ?

By the way, I didn't see the file `${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js`
but I have see someone said that this file is not needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- instead of 'debug in exponent' select 'attach to packager' (**but dont click the green arrow yet**)
- change the *packager port* (because expo packager defaults to 19001 instead of 19000)) by adding the line ***"react-native.packager.port": 19001*** to user's settings.json
- run the app on metro's web ui or by command line (*npm run ios/android* [or yarn])
- click the green arrow to start debuging on vscode
- then start the "Remote JS Debugging" on simulator, emulator or device