# How do I debug React Native with VSCode on Expo?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I'm sorry, I was able to get this all to work yesterday, but I can't get Expo to attach to my VS Code Debugger today, with various problems.

At this moment I have no server running. Expo is open in my simulator. I hit "run" on "Debug in Expo" from VS Code and I get this error:

```
(node:16799) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)
    at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG/Learning/Tuz1App/node_modules/sane/src/fsevents_watcher.js:41:11)
    at createWatcher (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG/Learning/Tuz1App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:780:23)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HasteMap._watch (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG/Learning/Tuz1App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:936:44)
    at _buildPromise._buildFileMap.then.then.hasteMap (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG/Learning/Tuz1App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:355:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:16799) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16799) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[Error] Error: Could not start the packager.
```

Let's start the server and see what happens...
Server loads, all good. I haven't selected "Run" from the Metro screen.

Let's try running the debugger again and see what happens...

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1256:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1304:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1392:7)
    etc...
```

Makes sense, npm is running on port 8081. I can load the project in Expo; when I do, it opens up a chrome debug window. Let's hit "Stop Remote Debugging" and see if we can run the debugger from VS Code again (probably not since the port is still in use. -- right, same error.)

Ok now that we've disabled remote debugging in expo, let's stop the server and maybe try to restart from VS Code? Nope. Simple error:

```
[Error] Error: Could not start the packager.
```

Any help? I KNEW I should have written down all the steps I took yesterday!

Comment: I answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772013/vscode-debug-expo-project-debug-adapter-process-has-terminated-unexpectedly/56119097#answer-56119097). In short, you need to select 'attach to packager' and change the _packager port_ (that defaults to 19000) to metro port (19001)